# sales_order_creditmemo_save_after triggers sales_order_invoice_save_after

Tags: event-observer

I have an observer listening for events that fire `sales_order_creditmemo_save_after`. The issue I have is that when a credit memo is saved on the invoice, the `sales_order_invoice_save_after` event is also fired - which causes issues with my code, because I also have another observer listening on that event.

For the observer listening on `sales_order_invoice_save_after` - is there a way to distinguish whether the event was a credit memo or an invoice?

I have found deep down in the `$observer` object, `protected '_historyEntityName' => string 'creditmemo' (length=10)` however is there a more standard way to access this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The work around was to add a conditional check on the `sales_order_invoice_save_after` to look for the order status label. Because I only needed the observer to work when the order status was 'Processing', I was able to use:

`if ($order->getStatusLabel() == 'Processing')`

However I am yet to find a way to access `protected '_historyEntityName' => string 'creditmemo' (length=10)` in the observer object.

Comment: I just grepped in the Magento core for `_historyEntityName`. It is used very rarely and you do not have any chance to access it from the outside.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Mage::register($name,$value)` and `Mage::registry($name)` to solve this issue.

Inside your `sales_order_creditmemo_save_after` event add this:

```
$orderid = $observer->getEvent()->getCreditmemo()->getOrderId();
Mage::register('creditmemo_created_for_order_'.$orderid,true);
```

At the beginning of your `sales_order_invoice_save_after` event, add this:

```
$orderid = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice()->getOrderId();
if(Mage::registry('creditmemo_created_for_order_'.$orderid)) { return; }
```

What this will do is store the value "true" into a temporary cache (Mage::registry) that is accessible from any script for that ONE request. Once the page has finished loading, that value is no longer stored.

Because both events are triggered in one request, it means that the first event (sales_order_creditmemo_save_after) stores the value and the second event (sales_order_invoice_save_after) checks for it's existence and if it exists it will exit out of your observer function.